# parsing json file with jq

Tags: json, shell, parsing, jq

```
{
   "name": "ford",
   "availableVersions": [
      {
         "version": 111,
         "count": 3
      },
      {
         "version": 122,
         "count": 2
      },
      {
         "version": 133,
         "count": 3
      },
      {
         "version": 144,
         "count": 1
      }
                          ],
       "RealVersion": 155


}
{
   "name": "bmw",
   "availableVersions": [
     {
         "version": 244,
         "count": 1
     },
     {
      "version": 255,
      "count": 3
     }                  ],
     "RealVersion": 120

    }
```

I have this demo.json file now `if (name == 'ford')`(name can be a variable) I want to get the all the versions whose `count != 3`
and if all the version's `count == 3` I want to get the RealVersion of ford so in this case output should be.

`EXPECTED OUTPUT = [122 144 ]`
I am using jq tool for parsing the json file

Now if all the version count ==3

```
      {
   "name": "ford",
   "availableVersions": [
      {
         "version": 111,
         "count": 3
      },
      {
         "version": 122,
         "count": 3
      },
      {
         "version": 133,
         "count": 3
      },
      {
         "version": 144,
         "count": 3
      }
                          ],
       "RealVersion": 155


}
{
   "name": "bmw",
   "availableVersions": [
     {
         "version": 244,
         "count": 1
     },
     {
      "version": 255,
      "count": 3
     }                  ],
     "RealVersion": 120

    }
```

Now in this case all the version's count == 3 so now I want to get the real version which is 155
`EXPECTED OUTPUT SHOULD BE 155`

CAN ANYONE HELP ME WITH THIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program, when invoked with the -n command-line option, produces the expected output in both cases:

```
inputs
| .RealVersion as $RealVersion
| select(.name == "ford")
| .availableVersions
| map(select(.count != 3))
| if length > 0 then map(.version)
  else $RealVersion
  end
```

Specifically, in the first case, it produces a JSON array, and in the second case, the actual value of `.ReadVersion`.

Comment: cat jsonfile | jq  '.RealVersion as $RealVersion | select(.name == "ford") | .availableVersions |  map(select(.count != 3)) | if length > 0 then map(.version) else $RealVersion'                                    I am using this command but still it is not working. It is giving me an error

Comment: Your program differs from the one given.

Comment: Thanks it worked . Is there a way in which i don't get a json array i want to store versions in a normal array and if there is only the realversion i want to store that also in an array?